# Stop flex wrap from vertical centering

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using `flex:wrap;` to display a grid with 4 rows of 4, 100px * 100px divs, in a container of 400px * 400px.  This works fine however, I want to display another grid with 2 rows of boxes in the same size container, here flex centres the second row in the box instead of displaying it on the next line.  How can I stop this
centring?

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing your code.  Have you tried `flex-direction: column`

Comment: My blind guess is that you should use `vertical-align:top`, because that's all I can think of without seeing the code.

Comment: @MrLister It is flex items and `vertical-align` doesn't have any effect on them...and I'm pretty sure this is an `align-content` issue, which will have the mentioned effect for wrapped flex items

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you might be experiencing is the nature of when the box is filling its parents entire size.   This can happen when you have multiple divs nested within each other where their heights and widths are both 100%, and the content centers by default in that scenario.

The solution is going to be to make sure that your inner content has its height set to "auto", like so:

```
<div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: 50% 50%">
<div>
    <h4>Vertical Centering Problem</h4>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="innerWrong">
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>Vertical Centering Solution</h4>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="innerRight">
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS here:

```
.outer { width: 500px; height: 400px; background-color: maroon; overflow: hidden; overflow-Y: auto; }
.innerWrong { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.innerRight { width: 100%; height: auto; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.content { margin: 10px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: silver; }
```

See this code pen that I created, it demonstrates the problem that I think you might be having, and the solution to it.

Code Pen:  https://codepen.io/mikeallen811/pen/abYBVrb

Hope that helps!